Why did Go print an error instead of a string?
I am going through the example from Go "A Tour of Go" where I tried the error example. So, I modified it a bit and expected a different result.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    When time.Time
    What string
}

func (e MyStruct) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("######### %v, %s", e.When, e.What)
}

func (e MyStruct) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("******** %v", e.When)
}

func run() MyStruct {
    return MyStruct{
        time.Now(),
        "it didn't work",
    }
}

func main() {
    obj := run()
    fmt.Println(obj)
}


Here I am expecting fmt.Println(obj) in main() should print

******** 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001

But it's printing.

######### 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001, it didn't work


How did you modify it and why did you expect a different result?

This is documented by package fmt—see the section starting with «Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces. In order of application: <…>». In general, I recommend to first always consult the documentation.

In golang fmt.Println considering Error() method before Stringer method. When you have implemented Error and String method on a type, then it will print what inside in Error method first.
As in the fmt documentation under the section starts with Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p
4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any). 


Code reference :  handleMethods
....

case 'v', 's', 'x', 'X', 'q':
    // Is it an error or Stringer?
    // The duplication in the bodies is necessary:
    // setting handled and deferring catchPanic
    // must happen before calling the method.
    switch v := p.arg.(type) {
    case error:
        handled = true
        defer p.catchPanic(p.arg, verb, "Error")
        p.fmtString(v.Error(), verb)
        return

    case Stringer:
        handled = true
        defer p.catchPanic(p.arg, verb, "String")
        p.fmtString(v.String(), verb)
        return
    }
....
        



Please consider citing the documentation of the fmt package instead of its source code.
